# How dangerous is firing a bullet straight up in to the air?

Tags: gravity, speed

Question's title says it all how dangerous are the bullets which are fired up straight in to the air? I often find myself in this discussion where there are people who argues that it is harmless and some say it can be lethal at times. I want to clear my understanding about it to settle this issue once in for all.

Comment: see this article for a start: http://www.straightdope.com/columns/read/1199/can-a-bullet-fired-into-the-air-kill-someone-when-it-comes-down

Comment: Mythbusters did an episode on it, they found that bullets fired straight up tumble on the way down and represent fairly little danger, but those fired in a high but non-vertical angle could retain their stable flight dynamics and represented a much more serious risk. Certainly if you live in parts of the world both densely populated and where people fire guns into the air in celebration you will have heard reports of people injured or killed by bullets from the sky. //grew up in south Texas

Comment: Difficult to give a "physics" answer to this in anything like closed form, and I am tempted to close this. It might be better on Skeptics.SE, but they are still in beta.

Comment: Found Duplicate http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/610/can-bullets-fired-into-the-air-kill-a-person-when-they-fall

Comment: Thanks for the link, Haris, I'll close this one. The way you've asked it, it's not really appropriate for this site unless you quantitatively define what it means for a falling bullet to be dangerous.